# Comparing current user to a meteor list

Tags: meteor

I'm currently making a simple web app with meteor.js . I'm trying to implement a simple feature for my fantasy football league's custom site that I'm building.

Here's my code that's not working.

`{{#each users}}
    {{#if Meteor.userId() {{_id}} }}
        {{> ownTradingBlock}}
    {{else}}
        {{> userTradingBlock}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}`

So basically I want to render a different template if the user in the list of league members is the current user that is logged in. Does anybody have any thoughts on how this is creating an error, and/or if there's a better way to do it?

Here's the error code I'm getting.

.html:67 : expected space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a Meteor method within Spacebars. For this you will need to create a helper:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  isEq: function (id) {
    if (Meteor.userId() === id)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each users}}
  {{#if isEq _id}} }}
    {{> ownTradingBlock}}
  {{else}}
    {{> userTradingBlock}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You're the man. Thanks a bunch! I was looking into using a helper as I was waiting for a response.

Comment: No worries. Remember to accept answers if they solved your problem! Gooday!